# UICollectionViewCell Selection

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a problem with my `UICollectionViewCell` selection. I can not seem to figure out how to deselect all when I click my Edit/Done button. Tried several things, but none of them are working.. Here is the code so far.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (!editEnabled) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailDice" sender:self];
    }

    UICollectionViewCell  *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 5;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell  *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

}

- (IBAction)deleteButton:(id)sender {

    int which;

    if (!editEnabled) {
        editEnabled = YES;
        [[self toolBar] setHidden:NO];
        which = UIBarButtonSystemItemDone;
        self.addButtonOutlet.enabled = NO;
        self.CollectionCont.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
    }else{
        editEnabled = NO;
        [[self toolBar] setHidden:YES];
        which = UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit;
        self.addButtonOutlet.enabled = YES;
        self.CollectionCont.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
    }

    UIBarButtonItem* bbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                            initWithBarButtonSystemItem:which
                            target:self action:@selector(deleteButton:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = bbi;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the Apple Docs it says **["Collection views support single-item selection by default"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW8)** and you had mentioned "deselecting all" which made it sound like you might be trying to do multiple selection, so it might be worth looking into multiple-item selection for some answers if that's the case.

That said, for single selection I've used some code similar to what you posted using **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** and **didDeselectItemAtIndexPath** to add/remove a border when the user clicked on a cell.  But when they clicked a submit button I wanted the border to be removed from whatever cell was displaying one. For what it's worth, I used **didEndDisplayingCell** with the same code I had in **didDeselectItemAtIndexPath** to remove the border:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0
    cell.layer.borderColor = nil
}
```

**Note: This was asked forever ago, but I figured maybe this answer would help someone down the road.**